# Ledger Nano X not recognised in Tezos client

Tags: tezos-client

I just received the new Ledger Nano X yesterday. Currently the CLI client does not seem to recognise it. When I enter `tezos-client list connected ledgers`, I receive the following message:

> No device found. Make sure a Ledger Nano S is connected and in the Tezos Wallet app”.

The device works fine though with TezBox. Is there a way to fix this without an update for the tezos-wallet and/or Ledger app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communication with the Ledger Nano X is added in this MR, which is not yet merged - https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/merge_requests/1037